# How to pass smart pointers in function?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

In the following example, when I pass `p` to a function, It gets destroyed as soon as the function func exits

```
void func(std::auto_ptr<int> p)
{
   // deletes p
}

int main()
{
    std::auto_ptr<int> p(new int);
    func(p);
    *p = 1; // run-time error
}
```

I'm also told that passing smart pointers by reference is very bad design from the book "The C++ Standard Library - Reference by Nicolai M. Josuttis".

Quote:

> Allowing an auto_ptr to pass by reference is very bad design and you
> should always avoid it **.....**
>
> **.....**  According to the concept of auto_ptrs, it is possible to transfer ownership into a function by using a constant reference.

Is it not possible to pass smart pointers or have I got the wrong idea?

Comment: std::auto_ptr's are deprecated due to bad semantics like what that book is talking about ...

Comment: trivial edit required: "as soon as the function exits" (not "exists")

Comment: Is there any explanation to how was it possible to transfer ownership into a function by using a constant reference?

Comment: If the function has nothing to do with the ownership of the object, just pass the stored value. `void func(int& p); func(*p);` - There is no reason why the function should be concerned how the caller is managing their memory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Is it not possible to pass smart pointers or have I got the wrong idea?**
It only applies to `auto_ptr`. Also, as per the new C++11 standard `auto_ptr` is deprecated and `unique_ptr` is the superior alternative if you are using c++11.

The `auto_ptr` template class ensures that the object to which it points gets destroyed automatically when control leaves a scope, If you pass `auto_ptr` *by value* in a function, the object is deleted once the scope of the function ends. So essentially you *transfer the ownership* of the pointer to the function and you don't own the pointer beyond the function call.

Passing an `auto_ptr` by reference is considered a bad design because `auto_ptr` was specifically designed for transfer of ownership and passing it by reference means that the function may or may not take over the ownership of the passed pointer.

---

In case of `unique_ptr`, If you pass an `unique_ptr` to function *by value* then you are *transferring the ownership* of the `unique_ptr` to the function.

In case you are *passing a reference* of `unique_ptr` to the function if, You just want the function to use the pointer but you do *not* want to *pass it's ownership* to the function.

---

`shared_ptr` operates on a reference counting mechanism, so the count is always incremented when copying functions are called and decremented when a call is made to destructor.

Passing a `shared_ptr` by reference avoids calls to either and hence it can be passed by reference. While passing it by value appropriately increments and decrements the count, the copy constructor for `shared_ptr` is not very expensive for most cases but it might matter in some scenarios, So using either of the two depends on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass a std::auto_ptr, but you can pass a smart pointer that manages the number of references to it, like [boost::shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0_beta1/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm).